# Refresh an Arraylist

Tags: android

I have my `arraylist` taking my data from my sqlite database, when i deleted the data inside the sqlitedatabase i want to refresh the list i did this but it crash:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db;
        ListView lv;
        ArrayList<String> your_array_list  = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_historique);
            db=openOrCreateDatabase("Site2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS story2(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,adresse VARCHAR);");
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from story2",null);
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    long clic= id+1;
                    Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM story2 where _id="+clic+"", null);



                    if (c2.moveToFirst()){
                        do{
                            String site =c2.getString(1);
                            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(site));
                            startActivity(browserIntent);


                        }while(c2.moveToNext());
                    }
                    c2.close();
                }


            });

            // Instanciating an array list (you don't need to do this,
            // you already have yours).
            List<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();


            // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a
            // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your
            // array as a third parameter.
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    your_array_list );

            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())

            {
                do {
                    your_array_list.add(cursor.getString(1));




                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }cursor.close();
        }



        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_historique, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {    
                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM story2");
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

i think it's because i'am refreshing the `adapter` but i didn't do anything to it

Comment: Why not use cursoradapter with loaders http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: Show your LogCat please

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh your `ArrayAdapter` after you've deleted the underlying data set, you can call

```
arrayAdapter.clear();
```

Then you don't have to call

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```